# The method is not executing in Laravel blade template

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function changeStatus() {
        var confirmMsg = "Are you sure you want to change the status?";
        if(confirm(confirmMsg))
        {
            console.log("yes");
        }
}
</script>
```

```css
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```html
<td style="verticle-align:middle">
    <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        id="toggleSwitch" 
        name="toggleSwitch1" 
        data-toggle="toggle" 
        data-on="Enabled" 
        data-off="Disabled" 
        data-onstyle="success" 
        data-offstyle="danger" 
        data-confirm="Are you sure?" 
        data-size="normal"
        onClick="changeStatus()" 
    />
</td>
```

```
<td style="verticle-align:middle">
        <input 
              type="checkbox" 
               id="toggleSwitch" 
               name="toggleSwitch1" 
               data-toggle="toggle" 
                data-on="Enabled" 
                data-off="Disabled" 
                data-onstyle="success" 
                data-offstyle="danger" 
                 data-confirm="Are you sure?" 
                 data-size="normal"
                  onClick="changeStatus()" 
                   @if($organisation->status == 1) checked @endif
                   >
                  </input>
                   </td>
```

This is my checkbox in my table. I tried to the scripts required for the bootstrap toggle.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function changeStatus() {
        var confirmMsg = "Are you sure you want to change the status?";
        if(confirm(confirmMsg))
        {
            console.log("yes");
        }
}
</script>
```

So now my problem is, when I add those script the changeStatus method is not executing. May I know what is causing this issue here?

I tried remove the scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

and it is executing the method. But when I add back those scripts the method is not getting executed.

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  If the problem is entirely client-side in HTML/JavaScript then can you update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193)?

Comment: But I am using the bootstrap toggle script sir. Is it still okay to make it as runnable code snippet?

Comment: If that's part of the example then yes.

Comment: The CSS and JavaScript parts of the code snippet interface are for CSS code and JavaScript code, not for HTML code.  HTML elements which link to external resources can be included in the HTML part of the snippet.  Aside from that... What is the problem demonstrated by the code snippet?  What specifically isn't working as expected in that example?

Comment: I will fix the code snippet sir. The issue is sir, when I click the checkbox without adding the javascript and css for the bootstrap toggle, it works fine. It will execute the changeStatus method. But after adding the javascript and css for the bootstrap toggle, the changeStatus method is not executing.

Comment: *"the changeStatus method is not executing"* - It's executing in the example provided, so the problem may not be where you assume it is.  You may need to do some additional debugging to provide a [mcve].

Comment: BTW you don't need `</input>` to close the input field, see [MDN docs - HTML input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). The runnable snippet has errors in the browser console. I assume because of the laravel blade syntax. Your problem is not related to blade as far as the code shows. So remove the `@if ...` line just to let the example run, please? You don't have to say 'sir'.